# Porting C# to C++ with objects as method parameters

Tags: c#, c++

I am porting a math routine from C# to C++. I hit a problem with a matrix operation.

Original C# code

```
public static Matrix operator *(Matrix a, Matrix b)
{
    b = Transposed(b);
    return new Matrix(b * a.x, b * a.y, b * a.z);
}

public static Matrix Transposed(Matrix m)
{
    float t;
    t = m.x.y; m.x.y = m.y.x; m.y.x = t;
    t = m.x.z; m.x.z = m.z.x; m.z.x = t;
    t = m.y.z; m.y.z = m.z.y; m.z.y = t;
    return m;
}
```

My C++ code

```
Matrix operator * ( const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b )
{
    b = Transposed( b );
    return Matrix( m * a.x, m * a.y, m * a.z );
}

Matrix Transposed( Matrix& m )
{
    float t;
    t = m.x.y; m.x.y = m.y.x; m.y.x = t;
    t = m.x.z; m.x.z = m.z.x; m.z.x = t;
    t = m.y.z; m.y.z = m.z.y; m.z.y = t;
    return m;
}
```

Things would be fine except that passing b from the * operator to Transposed does not work:

Error : function call 'Transposed({lval} const Matrix)' does not match
'Transposed(Matrix &)' port.cxx line 474       b = Transposed( b );

Comment: Operators in C++ are typically instance methods, so your method should look like: Matrix operator *(const Matrix &b), and instead of "a.x", "a.y", and "a.z", use "x", "y", and "z".  You're converting to an instance method which doesn't use any instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work in C++ is because `b` is a `const Matrix&`, which intentionally, cannot be passed to an API expecting a non-const reference.

I will assume that `Matrix` is a `struct` in C#, not a `class`. C# Structs gets passed by value, not by reference. The C# `Transpose()` thus gets a copy of a matrix, whereas the C++ `Transpose` gets a reference.

To mimic the C# version, you can either

- Make it a `Matrix Transposed( Matrix m )`, i.e. pass the matrix in by value.
- Make `Transposed()` create a new matrix internally and populate it with the transpose of its argument, which can then be a `const Matrix&` as well.